# How to mask part of an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mask

I would like to know how to mask part of an image that is in BLACK & WHITE ?

I got an object that needs to be edge detected, but I have other white interfering objects in the background that are below the target objet ... I would like to mask the entire lower part of an image to black, how can I do that ?

Thanks !!

**EDIT**

I also want to mask some other parts (top part) ... how can I do that ?

Please explain the code because I really wnat to learn how it works and implement it in my own understanding.

**EDIT2**

My image is 480x640 ... Is there a way to mask specific pixels ? for example 180x440 from the image ...

Comment: When you say 'lower part', do you mean the lower part spatially, or in intensity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a [2-D grayscale intensity image](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html#f2-175) stored in matrix `A`, you can set the lower half to black by doing the following:

```
centerIndex = round(size(A,1)/2);         %# Get the center index for the rows
A(centerIndex:end,:) = cast(0,class(A));  %# Set the lower half to the value
                                          %#   0 (of the same type as A)
```

This works by first getting the number of rows in `A` using the function [SIZE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/size.html), dividing that by 2, and rounding it off to get an integer index near the center of the image height. Then, the vector `centerIndex:end` indexes all the rows from the center index to the end, and `:` indexes all the columns. All of these indexed elements are set to 0 to represent the color black.

The function [CLASS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/class.html) is used to get the data type of `A` so that 0 can be cast to that type using the function [CAST](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cast.html). This *may* not be necessary, though, as 0 will probably be automatically converted to the type of `A` without them.

If you want to create a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1) to use as a mask, you can do the following:

```
mask = true(size(A));  %# Create a matrix of true values the same size as A
centerIndex = round(size(A,1)/2);  %# Get the center index for the rows
mask(centerIndex:end,:) = false;   %# Set the lower half to false
```

Now, `mask` is a logical matrix with `true` (i.e. "1") for pixels you want to keep and `false` (i.e. "0") for pixels you want to set to 0. You can set more elements of `mask` to `false` as you wish. Then, when you want to apply the mask, you can do the following:

```
A(~mask) = 0;  %# Set all elements in A corresponding
               %#   to false values in mask to 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the code :) Can you please explain what the code does in detail ? I would like to learn how it works :) Can you also tell me how can I also mask a specific part instead of just half ? because it turns out that I need to mask a few vertical pixels from the top part of image as well .. THANKS !

Comment: @ZaZu: No problem. ;) I updated my answer with an explanation and code for creating a logical mask.

Comment: Thanks alot :) One problem though, the logical index used for masking does not work here :( Im not sure why !! The previous one works well but it cuts the the last point where the object falls (the object falls a bit after 1/2 image size) .. Is there a way I can use the first method to block the upper space as well ? **EDIT** Can I use a way to block specific pixels ? I have a 480x640 image ..

Comment: @ZaZu: Not sure why the logical index isn't working. What error message are you getting? You can block other parts of the image by setting other ranges of indices to 0 (like I did in the first example). For example, `A(1:5,:) = 0;` sets the first 5 rows to black, while `A(180,440) = 0` sets the pixel in row 180 and column 440 to black.

Comment: Alright !! I got it ... I had placed `mask(1:5,:)` instead of `image(1:5,:)`  .... Now I got the first few rows = false and im glad that it works :) thanks ... now can I mask these first rows AND the last 50 rows for example ?

Comment: Oh you already mentioned A(180,440) example, thanks it works now !! :)
Really appreciate your help and replying back !

Answer (score 0):

```
function masked = maskout(src,mask)
    % mask: binary, same size as src, but does not have to be same data type (int vs logical)
    % src: rgb or gray image
    masked = bsxfun(@times, src, cast(mask,class(src)));
end
```